# C++ 20 standard for netbeans?

Tags: c++, netbeans, c++20

I recently got to know about c++ 20 and it has got a great set of features. I am currently using Apache netbeans and cannot find any suitable reference to enable C++ 20 support. Is it still not in netbeans?

Comment: Netbeans is an IDE not a compiler. The support of c++20 depends on what compiler you have installed. Although if you do have a compiler that supports c++20 you will have to edit your settings in netbeans to enable c++20 as I don't believe any compiler currently defaults to c++20

Comment: Nor does any compiler have full support for C++20.